# HTML5 Big dataurl

Tags: php, html, canvas

I am facing this issue from last 2 weeks.

For managing canvas I'm using `KineticJS`.

`dataURL` of canvas is huge, in MBs.

I have tried to send dataURL using

- `ajax` post
- `ajax` data post using "application/upload" content-type

But with all tried ways, it is crashing browser on mobile device and Mac Mozilla browser.

My application is here. 
http://bit.ly/1hHSIGX

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

**Does it work for a small image (maybe 1/2 mb)?**

**If no**

Make sure you configure your server to allow uploads and assign a temp directory

```
file_uploads = On

upload_tmp_dir
```

**If yes**

Make sure you configure your server to accept large files.

```
post_max_size

upload_max_filesize
```

And your server may be timing-out so also check how much time you've allowed for uploads

```
max_input_time

max_execution_time
```

**Either way...**

The default file type created with stage.toDataURL is .png.  You can specify `image/jpeg` as the mimeType and your files will be smaller--often much smaller.  With jpeg encoding, you can also specify a lower image quality to reduce file size.

Comment: I am creating JPEG file. And I just again tested to create dataURL and not sending data to server. And it is still crashing browser. So I think it is crashing when it creates lengthy dataURL.

Comment: Ok, if your error is client-side, open up Firebug and check for errors. If you don't have Firebug installed, you can get it here: http://getfirebug.com/